# Borrar documentos de varias colecciones para mantener BBDD consistente

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Tengo las colecciones "articles, comments, favorites" en MongoDB y he creado el siguiente código en NodeJS + Mongoose para que, al borrar un artículo, se borren sus comentarios y los favoritos de ese artículo.

```
        //delete comments
        await this.commentsService.deleteArticleComments(articleId);

        //delete favorites
        await this.favoritesService.deleteArticleFavorites(articleId);

        //delete article
        await this.articlesService.deleteArticle(articleId);
```

El problema es que si se produce un error en el borrado de los favoritos o los comentarios, el artículo no se borrará y quiero saber si hay una forma de ejecutar todas estas operaciones simultáneamente y controlar que, si no se pueden realizar todas, no se realice ninguna.

Comment: puedes usar transacciones https://mongoosejs.com/docs/transactions.html

Answer (score 0):

Lo he solucionado de la siguiente manera:

```
    const session = await this.articleModel.collection.conn.startSession();
    session.startTransaction();
    try {
        //delete comments
        await this.commentModel.deleteMany({articleId});
        //delete favorites
        await this.favoriteModel.deleteMany({articleId});
        //delete article
        await this.articleModel.deleteOne({"_id": articleId});

        await session.commitTransaction();
    } catch (error) {
        // If an error occurred, abort the whole transaction and
        // undo any changes that might have happened
        await session.abortTransaction();
        throw new HttpException('Error deleting article', HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    } finally {
        session.endSession();
    }
```